# null pointer exception while instantiating content resolver?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-contentprovider

In my Android, I am reading the contacts by using content resolver.But content resolver is not getting initialized ,it gives `NullPointerException`. 
I want to use the string arrays in another class and to get values in them I have to query the database and read contacts from phone,but stuck with that exception as pointed out in code:

```
//this code is in some other class...     
et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchcontact);
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int
             count) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 lva.getFilter().filter(s);

RefreshListView rlv=new RefreshListView();<----class is getting called from here
                 lva.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                 lva = new ListViewAdapterContacts(AllContactsActivity.this, rlv.names, rlv.types, rlv.phones, rlv.ids);

                 lv.setAdapter(lva);


             }

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
             int after) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                 // TODO Auto-generated  method stub


            // lva.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
             });

...............********.........

public class RefreshListView extends ListActivity{

            String[] names,phones,types,ids;
            String name,id,phoneNumber;
            int type;
            ArrayList <String> newValues;

        public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);

        newValues=SetNewList.getNames();
        getContacts();
    }



public void getContacts(){
                int foo = 0;


    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();<---//null pointer exception

    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        null, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + ") ASC");
                if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

                    names = new String[cur.getCount()];
                    phones = new String[cur.getCount()];
                    types = new String[cur.getCount()];
                    ids = new String[cur.getCount()];

                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                        name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        for(int i=0;i<=newValues.size();i++){           
                            if(newValues.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                id = cur.getString(cur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                                String hasPhone = cur
                                .getString(cur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                                if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) == 1) {

                                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = " + id, null, null);

                                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                        phoneNumber = phones
                                        .getString(phones
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                                        type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                                    } // while

                                    phones.close();
                                }// if

                                else {
                                    phoneNumber = "unknown";
                                    type = 0;

                                }// else



                                phones[foo] = phoneNumber;
                                names[foo] = name;
                                ids[foo] = id;

                                if (type == 0) {
                                    String value = "unknown";
                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }

                                else if (type == 1) {
                                    String value = "home";
                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }// if

                                else if (type == 2) {
                                    String value = "mobile";
                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }// else if

                                else if (type == 3) {
                                    String value = "Work";
                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }

                                else if (type == 4) {
                                    String value = "Workfax";
                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }

                                else if (type == 5) {
                                    String value = "Home Fax";
                                    types[foo] = value;

                                } else if (type == 6) {
                                    String value = "Pager";
                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }

                                else {
                                    String value = "Other";

                                    types[foo] = value;
                                }

                                foo++;
                            }
                        }
                    }// while
                }// if


            }// get contacts

        }
```

Comment: RefreshListView()-->it is a constructor.

Comment: Don't use a constructor in an Android `Activity` - that isn't how an `Activity` works. The Android OS is responsible for handling construction - use the standard `onXXXXX(...)` methods such as `onCreate(...), `onStart(...)`, `onResume(...)` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this...

```
public class RefreshListView extends ListActivity{

    public RefreshListView() {

        ...

    }
}
```

Do not use a constructor for an Android `Activity`!!!

You should remove that constructor and put the code into the `Activity` `onCreate(...)` method.

See the documentation for [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and also read [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html).

Try something like this...

```
public class RefreshListView extends ListActivity{

    String[] names,phones,types,ids;
    String name,id,phoneNumber;
    int type;
    ArrayList <String> newValues;
    ContentResolver cr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cr = getContentResolver();
        newValues=SetNewList.getNames();//getnames is of static type
        getContacts();
    }

    public void getContacts() {
        int foo = 0;

        // REMOVE THE NEXT LINE !!!
        // ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: wow, I was unable to realize this was a constructor, I thought it was a method... +1(facepalm)

Comment: @hovanessyan: lol, took me a while to spot it. Seeing a constructor in  an `Activity` is such an alien thing, it wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: but how can i use on create when I am not starting activity through calling intent.by the way I tried on create but the class is not even getting started

Comment: @picaso: OK, it seems you don't understand what an `Activity` is. If you're not starting it as the MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` and you're not starting it using `startActivity(...)` with an `Intent` how can you expect the code ever to be run? Please read the documentation in the links I posted in particular the second one http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Comment: @MisterSquonk  I just want to use content resolver .is there any way it can be done without extending any kind of activity.I need to call that class by instantiating its object as we do in java,but I think content resolver doesn't work without extending activity.

Comment: You can use ContentResolver in every other application component, you just need a context - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html In the case of Activity, you automatically use the Activity's context. You can also use the Application Context - they basically differ in their lifecycles.

Comment: @picaso: So what does your app have in it if it doesn't have any activities? As hovanessyan says, you can use the Application Context but you at least have to have something which creates your basic Java class somewhere.

Comment: if you are using on create in an activity then content resolver  can be used inside a method,if that method is called from within on create so there is no point of removing the line which you are suggesting in your code.

Comment: "if you are using on create in an activity then content resolver can be used inside a method" - I would still move it to be a `class variable` rather than declaring it within the `getContacts()` method but that is just my approach. If no other methods require using the content resolver, then keep that line.

Answer (score 1):

[getContentResolver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver%28%29) should be  called inside an implementation of Activity - try overriding onCreate(). It's clearer if you call it as `this.getContentResolver()` in your activity = easier to read.

Check out [this example code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) (after "*Binding to Data*" section).

You can use ContentResolver in every other application component, you just need a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). In the case of Activity, you automatically use the Activity's context. You can also use the [Application Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29) - they basically differ in their lifecycles.